# What is currently the most stable version of Magento?

Tags: ecommerce, magento

I currently run an ecommerce store using Magento CE version 1.3.2.4.  There have been many releases that each have had a number of fixes and new issues since then.  I'm in the process of planning an upgrade and will be rolling out 5-6 new sites that will each be running on their own domain names, but will be using the same codebase and back-end as my main site.  I'd like to know what version the community recommends upgrading my main site to prior to this roll-out?  Should I go all the way to 1.6.2.0 or should I stop somewhere before that?

Answer (score 1):

ver 1.6.2.0 - Added January 11, 2012 according to http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Yes you should always upgrade to the latest stable version for security, features, and performance.

Comment: To make this question useful in future, you're basically saying "the latest stable version is the best" - is that right?

Comment: Well simply writing "the latest stable version is the best" is a bit brief. I explained the top three reasons people should upgrade. Security, features, and performance.